# SF dystopia book, 1980's, controlling machine eats people

Tags: story-identification

Read it in the UK sometime in the 1980's or possibly the very early 1990's, I can't remember if paperback.

A dystopian society where people are machine raised in creches until early adulthood (maybe accelerated growth but I'm not sure) 
The protagonist is some kind of agent for the ruling computer mind, at periodic intervals people have to enter booths to communicate with this machine mind (maybe for transportation as well) but sometimes they get eaten instead, they are broken down into pieces and used to provide nutrition to the semi organic machine.

After various tasks that I can't remember the protagonist gets sent to Release Day at one of the creches. A crowd has gathered, some are like HR to recruit new talent, some are unscrupulous work gang leaders who will sign the new people into near slavery, some are seeking pretty faces for the sex industry and some are just there to shout intimidation at the scared newbies because the world is way overpopulated and hungry.

As the agent nears the crowd the machine tells him it needs to feed urgently, he selects a woman shouting at the youngsters and talks her into joining him for a little 'adult entertainment', he takes her into a booth and, as feeding tubes rush out from the walls she hysterically cries that she doesn't deserve such a terrible fate, he stands guiltily watching as she is devoured.

Later there's a crowd forming in a park and they spot animals the size of elephants heading towards them, one man spies udders on one of the creatures and says they may have milk. A rush happens for this legendary food but the creatures start eating humans instead, cue panic.

Then some kind of flood happens and the machine mind stops working so anarchy prevails, the protagonist meets another girl, they pull a drowned man out the water and begin eating him raw as they're starving.

End of memories

Comment: Are you sure that you want to remember more about this book?

Comment: It's a good question, but I don't know if I feel right about voting it up.

Comment: FWIW, this level of inventive squick makes me think Vance, but I don't recognize this story.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron I guess if we know the title and author, we'll know what to avoid.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron - A sentient machine that eats people and periodically then feeds them to gigantic elephant creatures? How dreadfully mundane.

Comment: @DavidW The nearest thing in Vance to that sort of squick, I'd say, is the *implied* killing of children for immortality in *The Killing Machine* — whose title may be what made you think of Vance!